# Excel - Update table A with new data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table A that I want to update with the new value of table B located on another sheet.

To update each row of table A, I first need to check if the VAT numbers (one of the column of both tables) of table B is present in table A:

-CASE1: If it is then I update the value of the other column of this row

-CASE2: If it is not present then I create a new row in table A and then copy paste all the values.

I manage to do it manually but the problem here is that the table are getting bigger and bigger (>6000 rows). I know that I need to use vlookup function but I don't know how to make the disctinction between the two cases.

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

Comment: So with case 2, you need to add a new row when the VAT value of your row is missing? This is not going to be a vlookup formula but a vba code

Comment: Yes I was not sure to be able to do it without VBA, but manually it was quite easy. If VAT not found then copy the value of the row in table B and paste in at the end of table A.

Comment: You copy the whole row of Table B and paste it at the end of table A?

Comment: I added screenshots of the two table for clarity. Yes I copy the row of the cell with VAT number not present and then paste this new row in table A since it is new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do the trick

```
Sub VAT()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Table A")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Table B")


Dim LastRowA, LastRowB As Long
LastRowA = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowB = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim A, r, ra As Range
Dim k As Integer
k = 1
Set A = ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRowB)

For Each r In A

    Set ra = ws1.Cells.Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then

        ws2.Rows(r.Row).Copy Destination:=ws1.Rows(LastRowA + k)
        k = k + 1
        Else
        ws2.Rows(r.Row).Copy Destination:=ws1.Rows(ra.Row)

    End If
Next r

End Sub
```